# How to provide in-place autocorrection in Solr?

Tags: java, solr, autocorrect

Is possible in Solr to provide an in-place auto-correction?  Like Goggle:

[image]

If yes, then please tell me how?

Is it a Solr configuration? or some extra hand-coded logic after I get Solr's suggestions?

Because I'm already using Solr's suggester component and I'm not getting this in-place auto-correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the solr spellCheck component. The suggest component reuses already a lot of stuff. So it should be quite easy to add corrected suggestions.

See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Suggester and http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent#spellcheck.collateExtendedResults

You can use the collationQuery to ensure search results on click.

Comment: I'm already using Solr's suggest component (which it is a Spellcheck component).  It looks it doesn't provide this in-place autocorrection

Comment: have you explicitly activated the spellChecker (spellcheck=true) and configured it properly? something like this: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent#Configuration

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 components to getting your desired result.

1. (back end) enabling the spellCheck component(http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Spell+Checking)
2. (front end) using some sort of jQuery/ajax (http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) call to the server and using the results to auto populate the drop down with the results from the server